# Sample Java web application for simulation proposes (inclusive of database script and etc)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm currently trying to understand OpNet AppInternal Xpert.(Application Performance Management Software)

May I know where can I download entire JEE application including source code for deployment to TomCAT/weblogic servers?

prefer application with simulation for users and usage.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/sample/

Comment: that is too simple, I need something more complex like a trading software or something.

Comment: You can try using the Spring Pet Clinic example http://docs.spring.io/docs/petclinic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check this site http://www.programmr.com/frontkk have many J2E projects